# How to find site id for one site on a multisite

Tags: multisite

I am trying to migrate a site from a single site instance to a multisite instance.

I m using instructions at: https://pressjitsu.com/blog/wordpress-single-site-multisite-migration/

It states to

"...alter all the table name prefixes to wp_N_ where N is the site ID of the newly created site in the network. Renaming can be done using the RENAME TABLE query in a MySQL shell:

RENAME TABLE oldprefix_posts TO wp_2_posts;
RENAME TABLE oldprefix_postmeta TO wp_2_postmeta;"

can i find the 'site ID' of a site on the multisite instance using the WP Dashboard?  If not, how might I do it at the CL?

Answer (score 4):

From the Network Admin, go to *Sites > All Sites*. When click to edit a site you'll be taken to a URL like

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=1
```

That number at the end is the site ID.